How can I get just the first row of data from a google sheet within Vue?
I'm doing a small project where I'm connecting to a Google Sheet with a basic Vuetify website. I'm pulling in the data from the sheet directly to display on the website, but I only want to pull in the first row of data on the front-end of the site.
The code I have works to pull in everything, but I'm drawing a blank on just getting the first element in the array. Below is the relevent code:
     <div v-for="company in state.companies" :key="company.Company">
        {{ company.Company }} 
    </div>

I've tried {{ company.Company[0] }} but all that does is pull the first letter of each row.
Thanks in advance for any help.
EDITED FOR CLARITY
An example of the data being pulled in.
[
{
    "Layoff_id": 1,
    "Company": "Fall Damage",
    "Date": "2024-05-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Employees": 50,
    "Parent": "Fragbite"
},
{
    "Layoff_id": 2,
    "Company": "Hatchery Games",
    "Date": "2024-05-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Employees": 13,
    "Parent": ""
},
{
    "Layoff_id": 3,
    "Company": "Singularity 6",
    "Date": "2024-05-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Employees": 36,
    "Parent": ""
},
{
    "Layoff_id": 4,
    "Company": "Phoenix Labs",
    "Date": "2024-05-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Employees": 125,
    "Parent": ""
},
{
    "Layoff_id": 5,
    "Company": "GameLoft Cluj",
    "Date": "2024-05-16T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Employees": 136,
    "Parent": "Vivendi"
}
]

It's being pulled from a google sheet using the following.
onMounted(() => {    

const url = 'URL'
axios.get(url)
  .then(
    (data) => {
      state.companies = data.data;
      console.log(state.companies[0]);
    }
  )
} )

const state = reactive({
companies: []

})

I just need, in the front end of the site, to have the first set of data pulled for display (First company). I don't need/want it to display everything. as it currently does in the image below.


How does your data look?

It pulls in everything. This is the script code
onMounted(() => {
console.log('this runs from onMounted');
const url = 'URL'
axios.get(url)
  .then(
    (data) => {
      state.companies = data.data;          
    }
  )

} )
const state = reactive({
companies: []
})

No, what is the shape of your data, array with objects etc in it? Please update your question with a sample of the received payload and what you want in the end. So that it's more visual for your helpers.

I'm sorry, I hope my edit gives more clarity

Ok, I figured it out. It might not be the best solution, but it works.
I changed the onMounted function to the following:
  axios.get(url)
.then((response) => {
  if (response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
    state.company = response.data[0];
  }
})

Then changed the v-for to a v-if, like so:
     <div v-if="state.company" class="company-container">
      {{ state.company.Company }}
    </div>

Now, I'm getting the result

